# Inequality Equation

Tags: inequality

Why does this not work: $$6<5x-x^2\\ -x^2+5x-6>0\\ (x+3)(x+2)>0$$

And this does: $$6<5x-x^2\\ x^2-5x+6<0\\ (x-3)(x-2)<0$$

Shouldn't $ax^2 + bx + c$ equal to $(x + u) ( x + v)$ where $u, v$ are numbers that if you add together you get $b$ (in this case $5$) and if you multiply you get $(a \cdot c)$ in this case $6$.
That's how I remember being taught anyway could be remembering wrong.

Comment: Why do you think the first "this" should work? $-x^2+5x-6$ is not the same thing as $(x+3)(x+2)$ - the latter is the same as $x^2+5x+6$.

Comment: The last line in your first group is wrong. It should be $-(x-3)(x-2)$

Comment: If you divide by -1, as you do in the first case, you have to flip the inequality. For example -x < -1 is equivalent not to x<1, but to x>1.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Shouldn't ax + bx + c equal to (x + a) ( x + b) where a and b are numbers that if you add together you get "b" (in this case 5) and if you multiply you get (a * c) in this case 6. Probably should've added my reasoning in the question itself

Comment: This is called "Vieta formulas" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) and, the way you have learned them, they hold only if the leading coefficient (the multiplier of $x^2$) is $1$. So, "$x^2+bx+c=(x+u)(x+v)$ holds with $u,v$ such that $u+v=b, uv=c$" is a valid statement, thanks to the fact that we have the term $x^2$ alone (i.e. multiplied by $1$). In your first derivation, however, it is multiplied by $-1$ (you have $-x^2+5x-6$), so you first extract that minus ($-(x^2-5x+6)$) and then factorize the expression in brackets the way you've learned ($-(x-3)(x-2)$).

Comment: @StinkingBishop Aaah I see. Thank you.